# How can I convert MDI Icons to SVG Path?

Tags: svg, trumbowyg

I am using `trumbowyg` and I need to create some of the custom SVG icons from MDI (Material Design Icons) Icons

Example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="trumbowyg-blockquote" viewBox="0 0 72 72">
        <path d="............."></path>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="trumbowyg-fullscreen" viewBox="0 0 72 72">
        <path d="............."></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Is there a tool that can convert a MDI Icon to SVG so that I can use it with `trumbowyg`

Answer (score 0):

First convert MDI to TIFF provide by Microsoft itself (MDI2TIFConverter.exe) on https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30328, then convert the obtained raster image to vector format by a tool like `potrace` http://potrace.sourceforge.net/samples.html

Comment: I am referring to **Material Design Icons** not MDI file. I have updated my question. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, use this tool will do: https://icomoon.io/app